# Generalization of Binary Bracketing

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Is there possibly any natural approach to generalize the idea of binary bracketing (bracketing functions) to the continuous case, such that the well-known discrete version becomes a special case of the general theory?

Comment: What "binary bracketing" brings to mind as I read this is the variety of ways that parentheses may be paired properly in a line, related to [OEIS A036991](https://oeis.org/A036991), and the counting of which leads to [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  I'm not sure what a "continuous" analog of this might be, perhaps the manifolds of fixed dimension with [specified genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: I agree that the first thing that comes to mind would be the one you referred to, which leads to the Catalan numbers and all the other objects (all discrete) equivalently counted by them.
However, if one look at the bracketing functions (from the set of $n$ elements to itself) which satisfy some properties, I thought there might be a way to generalize the idea, by changing the domain of the function and taking care of the details. However, I am not exactly sure how feasible the idea is!

Comment: But, what partly tempts me to think there must be a sort of generalization is exactly the existence of those many equivalent objects which are all counted by Catalans. Namely, I feel some of them should have more potential than the others for a natural generalization.

Comment: It would improve your Question if you gave a result in the discrete case that you'd hope to generalize to a continuous setting.  Perhaps the result is "counting by Catalan numbers", but even so this should appear in the Question itself.

Comment: Although it is not clear to me whether or not you consider it as a result of studying (discrete) binary bracketing, I could mention the graded, non-associatvie binary system that we construct by the union of all Tamari lattices which we associate to the binary bracketing of $n$ objects. It might have the reasonable grounds to ask my question. I can elaborate on it a bit more, if you think that might help.